# Simple JFrame program but can't see JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I'm trying to learn Swing on my own. 
I'm playing with a toy program that asks the user to input their name. I put a JLabel and JTextfield into a JPanel where the user can input their name and submit. However my JTextfield is squished up and invisible and I can't get it to show (I've tried "setSize" to no avail).

[image: Invisible JTextField]

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class NamePrompt extends JFrame{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String name;

    public NamePrompt(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel enterYourName = new JLabel("Enter Your Name Here:");
        JTextField textBoxToEnterName = new JTextField();
        textBoxToEnterName.setSize(40, 10);
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.add(enterYourName);
        panelTop.add(textBoxToEnterName);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(new SubmitButton());
        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.add(submit);

        //Add panelTop to JFrame
        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //JFrame set-up
        setTitle("Name Prompt Program");
        setSize(300, 150);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamePrompt promptForName = new NamePrompt();
        promptForName.setVisible(true);


    }
```

Comment: `textBoxToEnterName.setSize(40, 10);`  See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JTextField textBoxToEnterName = new JTextField(20);
```

See [`new JTextField(columns)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28int%29) for explanation.  E.G.

[image: NamePrompt]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NamePrompt extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    String name;

    public NamePrompt(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel enterYourName = new JLabel("Enter Your Name Here:");
        JTextField textBoxToEnterName = new JTextField(21);
        //textBoxToEnterName.setSize(40, 10);
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelTop.add(enterYourName);
        panelTop.add(textBoxToEnterName);

        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        //submit.addActionListener(new SubmitButton());
        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
        panelBottom.add(submit);

        //Add panelTop to JFrame
        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //JFrame set-up
        setTitle("Name Prompt Program");
        //setSize(300, 150);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamePrompt promptForName = new NamePrompt();
        promptForName.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a longer but really thin line (I can see a tiny bit of the top of the text I'm typing)

Comment: Don't call `setSize()` (anywhere in the code)!  See the update.

Comment: It works! Can you explain why not to call setSize()? And also, how can I move the text box to be positioned under the text?

Comment: I put a comment to the question, that links to a [thread where the Gurus provide the details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556).  In this case, if the UI needs more 'white space' (e.g. more height to the dialog) this can be achieved in some cases by using layout padding (often declared in the constructor) or an `EmptyBorder` applied to the relevant panel.

Comment: If you are really new to GUI programming take a look at the Java Docs, for they provide really good info on different methods for Swing components.